# Who is the daughter of John Spartan in Demolition Man?

Tags: character, demolition-man

In [Demolition Man](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demolition_Man_%28film%29) is it revealed what happened to John Spartan's (Sylvester Stallone) daughter? I know his wife died while he is frozen. But what happened to his daughter? Is she Lenina Huxley (Sandra Bullock) or someone else? Did I miss something or is it kept unrevealed?

Comment: If she grows up to be Lenina Huxley that would have made the sex scene even weirder than it already was!  It think it's safe to assume that it wasn't Lenina.

Comment: Also a scene cut out of the movie is when John Spartan infiltrates the cryo-prison killing new recruits to Simon Phoenix's criminal gang. Also John Spartan fights that henchman to Simon Phoenix played by Jesse "The Body" Ventura who did the work in killing Raymond Cocteau. John Spartan's daughter was cut out to shorten running time. Maybe Lenina Huxley could be the step mother of John Spartan's daughter in a sequel if it happened.

Comment: @AidanO Especially since *Lenina* would most probably have known who her father is, anyway.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[**Marco Brambilla**](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0104193/), the director, [mentions](http://www.kqek.com/dvd_reviews/d/3918_DemolitionMan.htm) in the DVD audio commentary:

> ... **a number of small scenes and a subplot involving Stallone’s character meeting his daughter, now considerably aged since his freezing, that were trimmed or entirely deleted**, as well as a scene initially shot with [Lori Petty](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001614/) playing Stallone’s female sidekick and love interest before she was replaced by [Sandra Bullock](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000113/).

The [IMDb Trivia page](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0106697/trivia) also mentions this:

> According to the commentary found on the RC1 DVD, **there were some scenes deleted from the movie including a subplot involving Spartan's daughter** and the murder of Zachary Lamb by Phoenix.

According [to this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LNhs99lO9dE&t=3m20s):

> [image: Kate]

the woman on the far right is John's daughter.

Comment: I had forgotten about the character of Resistance Leader played by Dennis Leary LOL

Comment: Oliver_C is right. It comes up in the book version of the movie (which I've read). Also if you look at the shootout scene in the underground society (roughly 1:29:03) he's shielding a woman, the same woman from the image Oliver_C posted. It's his daughter.